# Criar intent para os botões do drawer layout , botão do drawer , ao clicar parece apenas um texto

Tags: android

Como faço para os botões do drawer layout me levar para outra tela?  tentei desta forma , mas nao deu certo
 Uma outra coisa , quando clico no menu do drawer , ele parece que é apenas um texto , não da aquele efeito de clique , vou deixar meu MainActivity inteiro abaixo

```
    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.testando) {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testando);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it= new Intent(MainActivity.this, 
               Ingredientes.class);
            }
        });
```

### MainActivity Inteiro

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Toolbar toolbar;
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    toggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")

public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.testando) {
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testando);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent it= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ingredientes.class);
            }
        });


    } else if (id == R.id.passo1) {


    } else if (id == R.id.passo2) {


    } else if (id == R.id.passo3) {


    } else if (id == R.id.passo4) {


    } else if (id == R.id.passo5) {


    } else if (id == R.id.passo6) {


    } else if (id == R.id.passo7) {


    } else if (id == R.id.passo8) {


    } else if (id == R.id.donate) {



    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não precisa criar um botão dentro do drawer, basta alterar o arquivo `suaactivity_drawer.xml` dentro da pasta menu.

No seu caso ficaria algo como

```
 <item
        android:id="@+id/testando"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"
        android:title="@string/testando" />
```

E aí na sua classe java seria só colocar da seguinte maneira.

```
 if (id == R.id.testando) {
    Intent it= new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ingredientes.class);
    startActivity(it);
 }
```

O mais aconselhável realmente é utilizar fragments atualmente, mas acredito que para o seu caso isso possa resolver.

Espero ter ajudado :D

Answer (score 0):

Falta adicionar o *ActionBarDrawerToggle* ao *DrawerLayout* e indicar qual é o *NavigationItemSelectedListener* que a *NavigationView* deve usar:

```
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
        this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
toggle.syncState();

NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Deve alterar o método `onNavigationItemSelected()` assim:

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.testando) {
        Intent it = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Ingredientes.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }

    ....
    ....

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

**Nota:**
Parti do pressuposto que está a usar a implementação padrão do NavigationDrawer no Adroid Studio.

Comment: Na verdade eu precipitei, mas era apenas uma sugestão de navegação  com fragment. Vou fazer isso nos comentários.

Comment: Sei que a sua intenção era ajudar, mas, assim como as perguntas têm de ser objectivas, as respostas também têm de o ser e devem responder ao perguntado. :)